# Use the controller object's geometry to influence hook

Tags: mesh, modifiers

As far as I'm aware, the Hook Modifier (when a mesh is used as the controller object) only uses the transformations of the mesh rather than its geometry. I want another mesh's vertices to be hooked to the controller object's vertices (think point *A'* of the other mesh is the same location as point *A* of the controller mesh). Is there a way to do this with the Hook Modifier?

**Note**: I cannot combine the meshes because the controller mesh is involved in a cloth simulation and there seems to be no way to exclude certain faces from collision, so I had to separate the hooked mesh from the controller in order for it to not collide. As such, I want the vertices of the hooked object to hook to the controller object's vertices.

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you could do is:

Create cube 1 and 2. In cube 1 select the vertex that is supposed to be the parent, assign it to a vertex group. Back to *Object* mode, put the 3D cursor on this point, create an empty, give it a *Copy Location* constraint with cube 1 as *Target* and the vertex as *Vertex Group*.

Now select the empty, shift select cube 2, go in *Edit* mode, select the vertex that is supposed to be the child, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> > *Hook to Selected Object*. It should work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the empties or vertex groups?

Comment: Perhaps, I have tried other solutions but I couldn't make them work, sometimes I don't know why, it would be easy if we could parent the vertex of an object to the vertex of another but it doesn't seem possible. You can use an invisble object instead of an empty though. Maybe someone will have another solution...

Comment: I can't seem to find anything either. I'll mark your answer as the solution.